# Converting an abstract File to String in Java

Tags: java, file

How would I go about converting an abstract File path (of File type) into a String type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`File.getPath()` will give you the path as a String.

If you want the contents of the file, use either of

- [IOUtils.toString(InputStream,Charset)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) from [Apache Commons-IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/)
- [Files.toString(File,Charset)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Comment: toString() should only be used for debug (personal opinion)

Comment: @dacwe: +1, You're right. I don't agree 100%, but i see your point.

Answer (score 3):

Use [File.getAbsolutePath()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

check this link [Abstarct path to String as path](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

check the method  `getPath()`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get file path as a string is as below code:

```
String FilepathAsString = fileobject.getAbsolutePath();
Import required : java.io.File;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the contents of the file into a String, using google guava it's a case of

```
  String st = Files.toString(file, Charsets.UTF-8);
```

see the [Javadoc](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Of course this does require you to know the character set of the file. Files contain bytes, strings are characters, and there always end up being bugs when converting between the two if you don't actually know what the bytes in your file mean.